# Visual Studio Code doesn't show local branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

VS Code 1.52.1 on Mac

I want to checkout to a local branch `dev` using the integrated SCM, but the branch name doesn't show up in the list.

Cli shows all branches correctly:

```
% git branch -a

  dev
* master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master
```

But in VS Code `>Git: Checkout to...` shows only:

[image]

Where's the local `dev`? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I only clicked in the update button, and now I get to see the local branches.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is what I did. *I hope it helps someone*.

1. made the `SOURCE CONTROL REPOSITORIES` tab show:
   [image]
2. I am assuming you would like to see your **local branch** name here - rather than **master**.
   [image]
3. This is what worked for me:
   [image]

---

*If this answer does **not** help - please let me know in the comments so I can edit or remove it.*

Comment: In version 1.66.2, there is no place to type in a repository name. I was, however, able to right-click the repository that was showing up incorrectly and select "Close Repository" to get rid of it and leave just my branch's repository. Then the branch was selected showed up correctly in the status bar.